# Fast way of checking out same value of properties in two arrays?

Tags: javascript

I have to find a way to check same value of properties in two arrays.

Here are two arrays contain objects.

```
// carArray1

[
 { id: 1, driver: "Mario", carName: "Ferrari 488" },
 { id: 2, driver: "Solid Snake", carName: "Prious" },
 { id: 3, driver: "Link", carName: "Explorer" },
 { id: 4, driver: "Zelda", carName: "Genesis" },
 { id: 5, driver: "Ryu", carName: "Range Rover" }
]

// carArray2

[
 { id: 6, driver: "Chun-Li", carName: "Lamborghini" },
 { id: 7, driver: "Blanca", carName: "Camry" },
 { id: 3, driver: "Link", carName: "Explorer" },
 { id: 9, driver: "Kurby", carName: "Ferrari 911" },
 { id: 1, driver: "Mario", carName: "Ferrari 488" },
]
```

As you can see **carArray1** and **carArray2** both contain same objects id of 1 and 3.

I was thinking iterate carArray2 array using map method

```
carArray1.map(car1 => 
  carArray2.map(car2 => 
   car1.id === car2.id ? console.log("same property!") : '')
 )
```

I can expect "same property!" message twice in console but I want to make it happen without using double loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this quickly (`O(n)` time), first iterate over one of the arrays and put the ids into a Set, then iterate over the second array and check whether the ID of the current object is in the Set:

```js
const arr1 = [
 { id: 1, driver: "Mario", carName: "Ferrari 488" },
 { id: 2, driver: "Solid Snake", carName: "Prious" },
 { id: 3, driver: "Link", carName: "Explorer" },
 { id: 4, driver: "Zelda", carName: "Genesis" },
 { id: 5, driver: "Ryu", carName: "Range Rover" }
];

const arr2 = [
 { id: 6, driver: "Chun-Li", carName: "Lamborghini" },
 { id: 7, driver: "Blanca", carName: "Camry" },
 { id: 3, driver: "Link", carName: "Explorer" },
 { id: 9, driver: "Kurby", carName: "Ferrari 911" },
 { id: 1, driver: "Mario", carName: "Ferrari 488" },
];

const arr1Ids = new Set(arr1.map(({ id }) => id));
arr2.forEach(({ id }) => {
  if (arr1Ids.has(id)) {
    console.log('duplicate id:', id);
  }
});
```

Comment: You can even replace the forEach with a filter to get your union set.

Comment: Just one quick question... why is it better to use new Set() instead of just an array? Because set does not include same value inside of it unlike array? and it is faster to use has method instead of using indexOf method for array?

Comment: @GoonGamja Sets have lower computational complexity. To check to see if an object exists in an array, you have to iterate through all array elements, `O(n)` - in contrast, looking up an item in a Set is `O(1)`, just like looking up if an object has a certain property. `Set.has` is much preferable to `Array.indexOf` (or `Array.includes`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter to get the items which are similar in the two arrays.

```js
const array1 = [
 { id: 1, driver: "Mario", carName: "Ferrari 488" },
 { id: 2, driver: "Solid Snake", carName: "Prious" },
 { id: 3, driver: "Link", carName: "Explorer" },
 { id: 4, driver: "Zelda", carName: "Genesis" },
 { id: 5, driver: "Ryu", carName: "Range Rover" }
]

const array2 = [
 { id: 6, driver: "Chun-Li", carName: "Lamborghini" },
 { id: 7, driver: "Blanca", carName: "Camry" },
 { id: 3, driver: "Link", carName: "Explorer" },
 { id: 9, driver: "Kurby", carName: "Ferrari 911" },
 { id: 1, driver: "Mario", carName: "Ferrari 488" },
]

const similarItems = array1.filter(i => array2.filter(j => j.id == i.id).length > 0);
similarItems.forEach(function(i){
  console.log("same property!" + i.id);
});
```